# Auto Layout Swift 4 Xcode 9 For Multiple Devices - Am I doing it Wrong?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, size-classes

I am having severe difficulties finding a clear working world example of auto layout on multiple screen sizes. Most tutorials have basic stuff like a button thats centralised and then after adding constraints in Interface Builder it scales with the device. One button is simple but in my example for the iPhone 4: [image: iPhone 4]

There are quite a lot of labels / buttons and some that are not central. The above screen shot is exactly how I want it to look on all devices.

The app is for portrait only but I want to target all devices. I tried slowly adding constraints to items from the bottom up using a multiple of the superview to position and size items and then applying aspect ratio to UI Objects (got as far as the got it button but not the red arrow buttons) but as you can see in the next picture for the iPhone 8 plus... the white space isn't going to perfectly fill like in the iPhone 4 which will leave me with a big gap at the top.

[image: iPhone 8 Plus]

Is there a way I can change just the iPhone 8 plus layout in Interface Builder to build a layout that caters for the extra screen size?

The iPhone 8, SE and X layouts are equally awkward with extra white space.

I tried size classes but that changes it for all phones.

Is there a way to centre what I have done so far?

How do you guys position objects in auto layout that are not centred?

Am I going about it the wrong way by applying X / Y constraints using a multiple of the superview? - same for the width. I'm only specifying widths as a multiple of the superviews width then adding aspect ratio.

I just need a real world working example I can learn the basics from or a system to create for multiple devices that I can follow. I don't want to use a 3rd party library.

I really hope someone can help point me in the right direction!

Krivvenz.

Comment: To do the auto layout? - You offering? :D.

Comment: No, to design your user interface. TBH, I'd not want to be using that. Too packed, not clear what it all does. To be fair, this is taken out of context, but still.

Comment: if your layouts are done right and you have a good UI/UX you shouldn't be running into this problem. You shouldn't want to have to just create another layout for *just* the iphone8 because it's messed up on it, you should try to set the constraints up so that it works for every screen. And I also agree with @LinusGeffarth there's too much going on and it's not what i'd be use to seeing on iOS it's very different.

Comment: Regarding your actual problem here, we can't really tell what's wrong because we don't know which constraints you have setup.

Comment: Indeed it is quite packed but it contains everything our users want and in context, its actually not to bad! It has all the information they want to see and access on one screen.

Comment: Yeah let's put the UI design issue aside here. Let's instead focus on your problem. Again, we can't tell what's wrong because we don't know what's going on.

Comment: @TNguyen - How do you position a UI object that isn't central using constraints so it remains the same for every screen? For example; the far left minus button in my screen shot.

Comment: If you can stick everything into stack views. If not start by chopping things up… The calendar icon can get constrained to the top right corner by itself. The title, text block, got it image, unlock button, and back button can all be one their own and centered horizontally in the container. Grab the as new and used labels and controls and stick them in a view, do the same with the red arrows and the shield section bits. Center those views horizontally too. then use greater than or equal to constraints and maybe some less than or equal to as well to prevent overlap and large blank areas.

Comment: No matter what you are going to have more space between elements on an plus sized phone than on a tiny little 4. Using the same spacing as the 4 on a plus sized phone is going to leave a massive white frame around everything, let the spacing open up on larger devices instead.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that sounds like some sound advice! Is that general practice though to position non central objects? It doesn't sound too good to add extra UI Views just to position things? Also, how will the calendar icon be constrained by itself at that position? It has a gap from the very top and right... which will need to increase / decrease with the screen size as well as the actual icon scaling.

Comment: @theMikeSwan I've started adding the constraints to the 4. How can I create additional space on a larger screen? The far left minus button, I'm using a vertical space constraint to the unlock button below: using the following:

First item: minusButton.bottom
Relation: Equal
Second Item: unlockButton.top
Constant: 0
Priority: 1
Multiplier: 0.98 

The multiplier being 98% of the Unlock buttons top y Position.

Comment: Proportional to what @J.Doe? - The superview? Just use the equal option in constraints and play around with the multiplier until its positioned where I want?

Comment: @Krivvenz, As an example you could add two constraints for the vertical distance between the Back and Unlock buttons. One could be greater than or equal to 10 and the other could be less than or equal to 20. That way the space between those two buttons will always be at least 10 points but never more than 20. Make sure the constraints make sense with each other (like less than 8, greater than 10 would never work). Also, keep in mind that the constants can be negative numbers (the bottom of the view holding the red arrows could be -50 to the top of the got it image

Comment: I would set that Got it image to keep its aspect ratio but let it grow and shrink to help with balancing the negative space if needed.

Comment: If someone can knock up a working example for me, with a similar design layout... using any old images / buttons and make it look the same on all devices, I will gladly pay like £20 or something... It sounds like some of you could knock it up in 10 minutes! Drag a few images, control click a few times and boom perfect layout for all devices. @theMikeSwan - Would you be interested? Not doing my actual project for me but just a working example I can learn from, demonstrating a few of the things you have said.

Comment: I think I'll try removing all the graphics and placing one at a time using some of the methods you guys have suggested. I've not tried using greater or less than constraints so that might be what I am missing to help fill the space or help position objects with more space for each device. Thanks for all the suggestions.